# Is it possible to set an application to preferably open in second monitor?

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors

As the title said, I want to set my Firefox application to always open up in second monitor. I'm using Xubuntu 14.04 and default ubuntu driver for NVDIA (noveau I think).

In Windows there is DisplayFusion that can this. Does Ubuntu have same equivalent app/combination key that can do the same?

Comment: ^If you just run the command to place the window on the second screen (defining coordinates), you have the answer :)